# Converting SSH2 Key to OpenSSH Format

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh2

On Ubuntu I generated a key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` command. 
While trying to convert the generated key to OpenSSH format with 
`ssh-keygen -i -f id_rsa.pub > id_rsa_openssh.pub`, I get error **uudecode failed**. 
Any idea how to resolve this error.

Comment: The `id_rsa.pub` file created by `ssh-keygen` (part of OpenSSH) is already in OpenSSH publickey format, and does not need to be and cannot be imported. Although it is used for SSH2 _protocol_ (along with the matching privatekey) it is not at all related to what OpenSSH calls 'SSH2' format, which is really the commercial Tectia-now-ssh-dot-com _product_.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Probably too late but using

```
ssh-keygen -e -f id_rsa.pub > id_rsa_openssh.pub
```

worked for me.

Comment: `ssh-keygen`'s `-e` command means `export`, and when no argument is given to it, its "default export format is “RFC4716” as per its manpage. `RFC4716` is the `SSH2` format by another name. In other words your command would convert the format TO rather than FROM `SSH2`. If it's already `SSH2` it likely just prints it to you in the format it currently has, inside the public key file.